# Adding an assembly reference to a script task in NAnt

Tags: build-process, nant

I'm struggling to get NAnt's script task to pick up a reference to a DLL outside the working folder.

```
<target name="UpdateDBs">
  <script language="c#">
    <references failonempty="true">
      <lib>
        <include name="\\srv-dev\sharedassemblies\OurCompany\DataTransfer\OurCompany.DataTransfer.dll" />
      </lib>
    </references>
    <imports>
        <import namespace="OurCompany.DataTransfer.WebDocs" />
    </imports>
    <code>
        <![CDATA[
            public static void ScriptMain(Project project)
            {
                WebDocDbPostbuildUpdater.UpdateSqlScripts(@"\\srv-dev\integration\OurProductSetup6.4\workingdirectory", new System.Version(6, 4));
            }
        ]]>
    </code>
  </script>
</target>
```

I get a build error:

The fileset specified is empty after scanning '\srv-dev\integration\OurProductSetup6.4' for: NAnt.Core.StringCollectionWithGoodToString:

I've tried a few different variations on this but got nowhere. Also the [documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/script.html) doesn't seem to make this particularly obvious.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sod's law. I just got the path wrong.

```
<references failonempty="true">
  <include name="\\srv-dev\sharedassemblies\OurCompany\DataTransfer\OurCompany.DataTransfer.dll" />
</references>
```